# Kubernates install Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp: lookup cloud.weave.works on 127.0.0.53:53: no such host

Tags: installation

Two days that I go around in circles on this error during the process of installing a master kubernates as excellently described by a site such as this one ([https://bikramat.medium.com/set-up-a-kubernetes-cluster-with-kubeadm-508db74028ce](https://stackoverflow.com)) and many others (thank you again very much to the authors)
blocking comes precisely from this command

**command **

```
$ kubectl apply -f "https://cloud.weave.works/k8s/net?k8s-version=$(kubectl version | base64 | tr -d '\n')"
```

**result**

```
WARNING: This version information is deprecated and will be replaced with the output from kubectl version --short.  Use --output=yaml|json to get the full version.
Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp: lookup cloud.weave.works on 127.0.0.53:53: no such host
```

I make this post to help many other people because the real problem was totally implicit. and therefore it was very difficult to find this problem on the internet and its solution, it goes without saying.

Answer (score 4):

Actually use this command instead

```
kubectl apply -f https://github.com/weaveworks/weave/releases/download/v2.8.1/weave-daemonset-k8s-1.11.yaml
```

because after research we realize that the path used by the path https://cloud.weave.works/k8s/net?k8s of several sites for the installation of the master kubernate, is acutely broken. At least until the monent I solved this problem. 23-07-12
I hope that will help